# Use check box or not

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I want to provide a form structure where in it, has a input type text and a drop down filed .
This combination multiples to the number of person in a respective database from the server .
Now when ever for the respective text field some value in the drop down is selected and then the form is submitted , the value related to that text field  and option value should go and sit in the database .
My question is ,
Is it feasible to monitor which combination of the above data has been entered by  having a check box or not ?
If so , then how to do it , as here each  checkbook will have two values one with respect the text field  and other is option value .
I have managed to multiple the text field and the option field and have ready the the data in them .
The only question how to handle it during submitting.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input tpye="checkbox" name="check_box"> 

foreach($_POST['check_box'] as $value) {
// your sql here
}
```